# Apple iPhone 4 flash memory

Tags: iphone, flash-memory

I read that flash memory has a certain amount of read and write operations which can render it unusable after it has exceeded the threshhold.

Is this something to be concerned about with regards to the Flash memory used in my iPhone, or is there a way to mitigate any ill effects of using it too much?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! There are a few questions in here, but it's hard to figure out what you are asking. Additionally, your question needs some cleaning up. This has the potential to be edited to become a good question, and if it does, we can re-open it, but first you need to clarify just what "dilemma" you face, and what advice you are looking for.

Comment: Your phone will become obsolete, break from a fall or have it's battery die out before you reach the limitations of flash read/write cycles

Comment: I have edited the question as I understood what the OP was trying to ask, and have worded it as such.  I think a genuine answer is able to be issued, and I have an answer should it be re-opened, hence teh vote to reopen.

Comment: Kindly reopen this question. Tnx stuffe for editing

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX is bang on. The theoretical limits of the sector's failure rate well exceed several decades.

Comment: I don't know anyone who has ever reached such a limit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia-page:](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory)

> Most flash devices are designed for about 100,000 - 1,000,000 write
>   operations (or "write cycles").

As you can read, the typical NAND flash has 100k+ write cycles, so I won't worry about that. Besides, I'm sure Apple has figured out some kind of system to increase this number by making iOS "drive-smart", meaning they've optimized the way iOS is reading/writing data to the flash in order to extend his life-cycle.
Like XAleXOwnZX said in his comment, the NAND flash memory will survive most iPhone life spans.

And another fact, it will take you about 140 years to wear out the same flash location. Most of the time, the data stays in the cache rather then it will be written on the flash memory.

I hope this answer comforts your concerns :)

EDIT: I've found what kind of flash is used in an iPhone 4. It's **Samsung K9PFG08 flash memory** and [this blogpost](http://theelectronicfreak.blogspot.be/2010_06_01_archive.html) tells you more about the typical reading and writing data and kind of confirms my findings above.

Comment: There's a massive difference between 100,000 and 1,000,000! Especially when multiplied by the number of sectors.

Comment: There is indeed. But since Apple doesn't give specific technical details about there used Flash, it's hard to find a concrete number...

Comment: I don't think it matters too much. All of today's flash memory that goes into consumer products like this have high ratings. They can last for decades. I was just making a remark.

Comment: Nope, is doesn't. That's why I said he shouldn't worry to much. In the mean time, I've found out what kind of memory is used in an iPhone 4 and something about his reading and writing behavior, which only confirms my findings.